# Elementary Probability Theory Chap 3 Exercise 14

Tags: probability, probability-theory, dice

> Three dice are rolled twice. What is the probability that they show the same numbers (a) If the dice are distinguishable, (b) If they are not.

The answer is (a)$\frac{1}{6^3}$ (b)$\frac{(6×1+90×3+120×6)}{6^6}$

I don't understand why (a) is $\frac{1}{6^3}.$ I think that since the three dice are rolled twice, there are 6 attempts. It should be $\frac{1}{6^6}.$

Comment: and by ".. the same numbers", it is meant that on the second throw, each of the three dice shows the same number as on the first throw? So consider the first throw. The result for the three dice on the first throw are
$$
4,1,2
$$
(for example). What is the probability that on the second throw, you get exactly this same result?

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is a bit unclear. Do you mean: You throw three dice, what is the probability that on the second throw you see the same numbers as the first throw?

In that case  for a) you want to see the exact same number on the same die as the first throw. The result of each die is independent of the others. As each die has $\frac{1}{6}$ chance to have the same number, we find for three dice your answer $\frac{1}{6^3}$.

Comment: I think that is what the problem is trying to express.